# How to make div states changing dynamically by JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div working as a button similar to the Youtube "Subscribe" button. There are 3 classes on CSS working as states and styles: .unactive (is not subscribed), active (subscribed) and .remove (when the mouse is over on subscribed).

Per example, when the button is '.unactive and mouse is over, add the class '.active'. Then when the mouse outs, it backs again to '.unactive'. If I click, its change to '.active' (and change the text inside to 'Subscribed'. And much more...

But when I add the class '.unactive' and remove '.active' dinamically, I can't identify/select the div again to remove the '.active' and back again to '.unactive'.

```
    $('.btn-circle.unactive').mouseover(function(){
    $(this).addClass('active').removeClass('unactive');
  });
  $('.btn-circle.active').mouseout(function(){
    $(this).addClass('unactive').removeClass('active');
  });
```

What is the best way to make it?

Comment: So... i got your point and what you want, but can you provide some css code? That would help! =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve this you can use `toggleClass()` to change the states on `hover()`. That way the element will return to it's original state on mouseout:

```
$('.btn-circle').hover(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('active unactive');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `.toggleClass()` could fix that?

http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

Answer (score 1):

You can make it as below mentioned.

```js
 jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(".subscribe-btn").hover(function(){
     $(this).addClass("active");
     $(this).removeClass("unActive");

    }, function(){
     $(this).removeClass("active");
     $(this).addClass("unActive");
    });

 });
```

```css
.subscribe-btn{font:16px arial; color: #000; border-radius:6px; padding:7px 20px; cursor: pointer}
 .subscribe-btn.unActive{background: #ccc; border:2px solid #666; }
 .subscribe-btn.active{background: #333; border:2px solid #666; color: #fff;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <button class="subscribe-btn unActive" type="button">Subscribe</button>
```